# alternative to have asp.net code behind in JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The `<%` is not recognised in the JS file.  What is the alternative to have code behind in JS file?

***Edited:***

how do i resolve like so:

```
function RefreshData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/home/default.aspx/GetData") %>',
```

Please do NOT show a similar answer outlined in this site as it is not an ideal solution: http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/07/17/resolveurl-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Can you paste some code and explain what is the goal of putting code in js file ?

Answer (score 1):

Passing the code behind data in parameters/variables. If your javascript is called from the ASPX page, then you can simply pass that data in a parameter.

```
myfunc(<%= mycodebehindvariableormethod %>, 'someotherparameter');
```

or in complex objects

```
myfunc({ par1: <%= mycodebehindvariableormethod %>, 
         par2: <%= someothercodebehind %> },
         'someotherparameter');
```

or

```
var complexObject = { par1: <%= mycodebehindvariableormethod %>, 
                      par2: <%= someothercodebehind %> };

myfunc(complexObject, 'someotherparameter');
```

Or you could put your data in a javascript variable, like...

```
window.MyData = <%= mycodebehindvariableormethod %>;
```

or putting it directly in your js objects, especially if they are singletons:

```
myjsobject.prototype.codebehindparameters = <%= mycodebehindvariableormethod %>;
```

and access these variables from your JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET file (.aspx or .ashx) as your javascript source. It will work

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/script.aspx" >

Your script.aspx is the original JS text without any  any <html> or <body> tags.